# Swift closure assistance for WKWebView evaluatejavascript

Tags: swift

So previously with UIWebView() I can get the user agent with,

```
UIWebView().stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")!
```

And so if I want to assign that to a variable I can just simply do,

```
var n = UIWebView().stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")!
```

My problem is that `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` is synchronous and returns a `String` while the replacement for the deprecated method is `evaluateJavaScript` for the class `WKWebView` is asynchronous. If my understanding is correct, `evaluateJavscript` also doesn't return anything, ie `Void`. As a result, I am having a hard time assigning the user agent found to the variable `n` as shown earlier.

My initial attempt was:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

var n:String = "TEST"
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var WKwebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            getUserAgent()
    }

    func getUserAgent() -> String{

          let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
          WKwebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
          WKwebView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent", completionHandler: { (result, error) in
              debugPrint(result as Any)
              debugPrint(error as Any)
              if let unwrappedUserAgent = result as? String {
                  n = unwrappedUserAgent
                  print("userAgent: \(unwrappedUserAgent)")
              } else {
                  print("failed to get the user agent")
              }
          })
          return n
    }

}

var test = ViewController()
print(test.getUserAgent())
```

But because `evaluatejavascript` is async `n` is still assigned to `TEST`

```
TEST
Optional(Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 14_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148)
nil
userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 14_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
```

Based on what I found from, [How do I get WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript to return data in a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615536/how-do-i-get-wkwebview-evaluatejavascript-to-return-data-in-a-function-call) ,the solution is:

```
func checkTitle (forWebView webView: WKWebView, completion: @escaping (_ titleString: String?) -> Void) {

   webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent", completionHandler: { (innerHTML, error ) in

        // Logic here
        completion(innerHTML as? String)
    })
}
```

However having played with it in the swift playground I'm still struggling to see how I can use `innerHTML` outside of `checkTitle` My understanding of closure is minimal so your help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to read up about asynchronous programming in general. The code here doesn't show what you intend to do with the result of the `evaluateJavaScript` call, so it's hard to give a concrete example of how it would be solved with asynchronous programming.

Comment: I want to get what's inside ```unwrappedUserAgent``` and use it outside of the ```getUserAgent``` function

Comment: Right, then just do as you did in your `checkTitle` snippet and use a completion handler.

Comment: @Claus, I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you show me what you mean?

Comment: If you don't know how to use closures in Swift, you'll have to read some tutorials first. There's plenty of resources that'll explain it in better detail than any Q&A style answer on StackOverflow can provide.